# Where is the specific driver for my GPU located

Tags: macos, terminal, mac-mini

I am trying to run a bitcoin miner ([bfgminer](http://blog.nwoolls.com/2013/04/24/bitcoin-mining-on-mac-os-x-cgminer-bfgminer/)), I know this is not efficient but I want to do it anyway.

The mac in question is a MacMimi running an Intel HD Graphics 4000 GPU and Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3615QM CPU @ 2.30GHz.  The os Mac OSX 10.8.5.

I have outlined my [problem](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17990/10116) on the bitcoin stackexchange site. I also did a google search and duckduck search with various combinations of the terms "Where is the specific driver for my GPU osx".

I am trying to hard specify the GPU driver for gpfminer when it starts as it is not detecting the GPU.

**What is the location of this driver on OSX?**

bfgminer specifies that is should be in the form of `erupter:/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART`

Comment: Where does bfgminer give that path - and is that for OSX or is that a Linux path?

Comment: It is an OS X path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On OSX the drivers are in `/System/Library/Extensions`

You'll find 3 files starting with `AppleIntelHD4000Graphics`.

Comment: Thanks, they are directories.  I just tried AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver.bundle/ AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsVADriver.bundle/ and neither works,... any other thoughts?

Comment: What about the kext (kernel extensions) ?

Comment: No, go. When I specify  `/System/Library/Extensions/AppleIntelHD4000Graphics.kext/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelHD4000Graphics` as the driver.